# extend the content of a block B into a block A

Tags: css

I have a class `red`, the width is of `60%`, I would like to put in this block another class which is named `green` with a width to  `70%`.

My problem is that in the display, the background-color `green` stays smaller that the background-color `red` , I don't understand why ?!

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="red">
      <div class="green">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: so the thing is the ```red``` box is the parent ```div``` for the ```green``` box and the ```green``` box use percentage width and height of its parent ```div```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width of a div is always calculated WRT its parents width.

Width of `container` is 100%

The div with class `red` will take 60% width of its parent. i.e, `container`.

The div with class `green` will take 70% width of its parent. i.e, `red`.

So `green` div will always be smaller than `red`.

If you want `green` to be wider than `red`, you need to put `green` outside red and inside `container` as below.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red">
    
  </div>
  <div class="green">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Understanding the problem**

`green class` is **child** of `red class` which means the width of `green` will be **70%** of `red` which is **60%** of `container`

> Let's do some Math -
>
> **Container** - 100% - *let's assume width x*
>
> **Red** - 60% of container - *0.6x*
>
> **Green** -70% of red - *0.42x*
>
> and we all know `0.42x < 0.6x`

---

**Solution**

Make `red` and `green` class two separated `div`.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example the red rectangle is 60% of the `.container` div's width.
Then the green rectangle is inside the red rectangle and has 70% of the `.red` div's width.

The divs were meant to be sibling tags as well I am guessing?

In short, the width is relative to the parent, not the body. Use the `vw`/`vh` units to work in hundredth of the view width and height, respectively:
https://riptutorial.com/css/example/17657/vh-and-vw

Answer (score 1):

It is smaller because the width in percentage is relative to the parent element. Therefore in your case, the .green is 70% of its parent .red which is 60 % of the width of the .container.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage